# Where to download Android sources while Kernel.org is down

Tags: android

I'm looking for the android sources that are hosted on kernel.org (according to this site: http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html). However since kernel.org was hacked a few weeks ago, it is down. Is there a friendly fork of the sources somewhere (e.g. github) for me to clone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed some parts available on github: https://github.com/android
But not everything I believe.

Comment: Thanks, that actually works. I had to adjust the repo config file for things to actually work but seems to be fine for now.

Answer (score 2):

My starting point for getting it from github is here:
https://github.com/cellcortex/github_android

--- edit

pretty much gave up on using the half-complete github forks. Instead I chose to use http://www.cyanogenmod.com/ which has complete android OS sources on github.